# Writing Python Files in Linux Server with permissions

Tags: python, linux, permissions, chmod

Currently I am writing a file to CSV from python. I need help understanding how to do this at the same time and while I write the file.

```
 import os
 import pd
 data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
 #I make changes to the file here
 data.to_csv('newdata_with777.csv')
 os.chmod('new data_with777.csv', 777)
```

Is there a way to make this happen on the same line?  Or a more efficient/better way of doing this?

Comment: Why would you make a csv file executable?

Comment: Are you trying to make the file creation and the os.chmod operation atomic? The usual way this is done is to write the CSV data to a temporary file, os.chmod the temporary file, and then os.rename the temporary file to the desired file name.

Comment: Have you tried using [`os.umask`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.umask)?